# Which charsets does varchar support? ie UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, varchar

Google failed to give a definitive answer.  So here goes Mr Stackoverflow...

#### Which charsets does varchar support in MSSQL?

i.e.  ASCIII, UTF-8 etc...

Comment: Collation is important: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175055.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `varchar` data type characters are stored as eight bit values, and the character set is determined by the collation that you choose for the field (or default for the database).

For example, the collation `Latin1_General_CS_AS` uses the Latin1 character set, and sorting and comparing is case sensitive and accent sensitive.

Comment: I've just opted for the default MSSQL collation